# Search refer to homepage

Tags: search, transcribe

Everything was working fine, 
Till suddenly [dynamic](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/dynamic_parameters.html) and classic [search](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/index.html#advanced-search-form) refers to homepage url?

The search refers to template result_page="search/results" but instead it goes to homepage (www.site.com) instead of www.site.com/search/results

First thing i have tried to figure this out is to remove the .htaccess but it didn't change anything.

Second i made a new template to test this, used the example in EE user guide but the results also takes me back to the homepage instead of www.site.com/search/results

It's not a server problem as i have a similar copy of the website on the same server and there it works fine
The only difference between both sites is transcribe. 
But i'm not sure that is related.

How should i go ahead and debug this to make it go to the result_page="search/results"

Thanks

Comment: "suddenly dynamic and classic search refers to homepage url" ... can you clarify? Please be very specific and detailed when asking questions!

Comment: Do other pages work? Can you access /search/results directly?

Comment: Yes i can enter the /search/results directly and it returns "Your search did not return any results" all other pages work as they should too. The problem is only when i search.

Comment: Can you submit any forms on the front-end successfully?  Make sure that your domain isn't changing ever - such as from www.example.com to just example.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok 
this is silly but it might help others, There wasn't any problem with transcribe

it was just in the EE configruation i removed the index.php from the "the  Name of your site's index page"

I've put the index.php the search is now being redirected as it should :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `result_page="search/results"` to `result_page="/search/results"`